# Build yocto for x86 Linux desktop

Tags: linux, x86, yocto

I want to build yocto sumo 2.5 for x86 Linux desktop. Does anyone have an idea or any documentation to do that ?.

Answer (score 1):

Please familiar with this doc - [Quick introduction to Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html), which consist information how to start and where to go next.

Comment: Thanks for the answer "lukaszgard" I have basic knowledge of yocto. But I want to port that it on intel-corei3 x86 native machine instead of an embedded board. there is one meta-intel(SUMO 2.5 – COFFEE LAKE) layer which supports only intel-corei7.

Comment: @Jayganatra what is your question then?

Comment: @Jayganatra "intel-corei7-64" machine should be 100% usable and compatible with any recent intel hardware (non-server hardwre anyway).

Answer (score 0):

meta-intel has "intel-core2-32" machine. you should use this or use qemux86.
edit your poky/build/local.conf file and set MACHINE to "intel-core2-32"

```
$ cd poky/
$ git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel
$ source oe-init-build-env
$ bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Answer (score -1):

1-) Install required packages

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev xterm sed cvs subversion coreutils texi2html docbook-utils python-pysqlite2 help2man make gcc g++ desktop-file-utils libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev mercurial autoconf automake groff curl lzop asciidoc u-boot-tools gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping
```

2-) Clone poky

```
git clone -b version git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git poky-version
cd poky-version
```

3-) Clone open embedded

```
git clone -b version  git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
```

4-) Clone meta raspberrypi

```
git clone -b version git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi
```

5-) Clone meta freescale

```
git clone -b version https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-freescale
```

6-) Clone meta ti

```
git clone -b version  git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti
```

7-) Clone meta-qt4

```
git clone -b version  git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-qt4
```

8-) Clone meta-qt5

```
git clone -b version git://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5.git
```

**version** : morty, rocko, sumo and so on...

**PS:** It works on the ubuntu 16.04. You can use these short guide and the packages can change according to linux OS.